# Twitter access/connection issues

Tags: twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I diagnose when and why a website is down?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7156/how-do-i-diagnose-when-and-why-a-website-is-down)

> **Related [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) Question:**
>   [How do I diagnose not being able to reach a specific website as an end user?](https://superuser.com/q/231977/289)

I consider myself to be fairly tech savvy, but I have a problem that is very strange: I can't access the Twitter website from my computer. No matter whether I try to view twitter.com or a user's profile, my browser just spins and eventually delivers the message

> *The connection has timed out*

My Tweetdeck desktop application also stalls and fails to connect. My Twitter app on my iPhone connects perfectly, even when on the same wireless network as my laptop.

How can I debug/fix this problem?

Comment: Try pinging twitter from your laptop to see if its dropping its connection (start -> run -> cmd -> type in ping ht tp://ww w.twitter.com (had to add spaces to stop in becoming a link.)

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm using a Mac, but received the following message: MacBook-Pro:~ macbookpro$ ping http://www.twitter.com
ping: cannot resolve http://www.twitter.com: Unknown host

Comment: Apologies Matt, I was using an incorrect command. It now says: --- twitter.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 179.304/180.916/183.367/1.745 ms

Comment: have you tried using another browser? and which one are you using?

Comment: See also - [How do I diagnose not being able to reach a specific website as an end user?](http://superuser.com/q/231977/289) on Super User